# Which read(2) errors are unrecoverable?

Tags: linux, posix

The [man page for *read(2)*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) lists numerous errors that can happen when calling read. Some of them are benign, like `EAGAIN`. Some are clearly unrecoverable, e.g. `EBADF` or `EFAULT`. And some are more nebulous, such as `EIO` or `EINTR`. However, the man page doesn't make any assertions about which errors are unrecoverable and which are simply a hiccup. Can all errors be classified as either fatal or vital?

The [posix specification for *read()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) reads pretty similar to the linux man page. It also adds:

> There are no references to actions taken following an "unrecoverable error". It is considered beyond the scope of this volume of POSIX.1-2008 to describe what happens in the case of hardware errors.

Is there literature on what to do in common error scenarios despite such actions not being strictly in-scope when discussing POSIX systems? Are there any extra considerations when writing portable code?

Answer (score 1):

These are a bit context-dependent:

- `EAGAIN` only happens on non-blocking file descriptors. Unless you set the nonblocking flag, you can treat it as fatal along with the others, because it should not happen.
- `EINTR` only happens when your process received a signal it did not ignore, and the process still exists. For this for happen, you need to have set up a signal handler. Unless you have done so, treat it as fatal.

The others you mentioned are also fatal:

- `EIO` is likely to be a hardware problem.
- `EBADF` is a problem in your program: you passed an invalid file descriptor.
- `EFAULT` is also a problem in your program: you passed an invalid buffer address.

In short: unless you do something special like asynchronous I/O and signal handling, you can treat all errors as fatal.

Comment: `EINTR` should always be handled in reasonable code, there's pretty much no case where it indicates that something horrible is going on, and plenty of cases where the appropriate response is just to shrug and retry. `EIO` is also not quite as bad as you make it out to be, and may be retryable. It *could* indicate a hardware error... or accessing a network drive while the network is down... or reading from stdin on a backgrounded process. Sometimes you want to give up, sometimes not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm starting to become familiar with the general cases. I'm just trying to make sure my implementation is exhaustive. If it's really as simple as, "anything except `EAGAIN` (and `EWOULDBLOCK`) can be considered fatal", great. But, as @hobbs mentions, I am skeptical about some of them, especially `EIO` and `EINTR` (although, as you mention, my program is currently single threaded). For example, if I receive `ENOBUFS`, is it possible that the kernel may free up resources and a future call will succeed (similar with `ENOMEM`)? Do you know of any references?

Comment: @hobbs, `EINTR` cannot happen if you don't have a signal handler installed -- either the signal is ignored by default, or it kills the process -- so a single-threaded app with no children can treat it as fatal.

Comment: Good code doesn't assume that it's running in a process where no one ever set a signal handler. That can easily change :)